# Pause upgrade halfway through?

Tags: upgrade

With my current Internet connection, it will take about 18 hours to download all the files needed to upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10. Is there a way that I can first download the files in the background and then do the upgrade? Alternatively, if I use the graphical Distribution Upgrade tool via Update Manager, can I Cancel halfway through the downloads and start again where I left off, or will it delete the files it's downloaded so far?

Comment: Yes. You can upgrade through a liveUSB or liveDVD.

Comment: @ToDo, how can I upgrade with a liveUSB? I've created one, but it's not recognised in software sources.

Comment: You don't 'upgrade' with it. You install the latest of your current install.It will keep your files and settings just like an upgrade.